# How to verify session and auth token in Vue 2 and Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-request

I have a project structure like **client folder** and **server folder**. Within **client folder** I have full Vue 2 project template using [vue-admin-lte](https://github.com/devjin0617/vue2-admin-lte).
Front end is working perfectly but where I am stuck is I need to authenticate each and every request to pass to **server folder**(running Laravel 5.5). Basically, how to compare and validate the access_token parameter sent from the frontend against the access_token present for each and every route.

Comment: Have you considered using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport)? It has built-in support for what you’re trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are currently using (from what little information you have given) is not a good approach. Try and use json web tokens(jwt) insted.

For info about jwt..
https://jwt.io/introduction/

To implement jwt in laravel try one of the following two packages

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

https://github.com/codecasts/laravel-jwt

The first one (jwt-auth) is a large package with customization options while second one (laravel-jwt) is very simple but cannot be customized